# How to get friends list of twiiter using twitter api on iphone app!

Tags: iphone, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get email of friends list using twitter api on iphone app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801040/how-to-get-email-of-friends-list-using-twitter-api-on-iphone-app)

Hi all, i am try to write app to get friends list of user on twitter, when user login twitter on my app.
I use twiiter api, but i can't do it. 
Please help me with the problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

If your Twiiter Api has this MGTwitterEngine.h file.Look for **getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus** method which give the list of your followers.

Use this Delegate Method from XAuthTwitterEngineDelegate

```
-(void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
{
mFollowerArray  =   nil;
mFollowerArray  =   [userInfo retain];
}
```

Comment: I just use getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus following:                                                         str =[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES]; NSLog(str); and str = CF5C7892-A9B4-42E2-97B4-F9CD09879D0E; i don't understand it. Please let me know it. Thanks you!

Comment: So now are you getting your followers list.

Comment: Use this delegate -(void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier {
  
 
 mFollowerArray = nil;
 
 mFollowerArray = [userInfo retain];
 
 
}

Comment: Thanks you, i will try success with -(void)userInfoReceived. but i can't get email account of people in mFollowerArray. Can you help me?

Comment: Emails are restricted.Only if your followers provide all access then you can use it.

Comment: Beware this only return 100 followers.

Comment: Hello Anand I use getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus and getUserInformationForEmail and its returns A212D011-6347-4D0B-BD62-6DC28CB288C8 , CDC19091-B463-48F4-9380-2CF9416A18A3 but i don't understand so please tell me what is this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to be sending a [GET statuses/friends request](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/friends) to the Twitter API.

For more information, you might want to read through that documentation I linked to, or re-ask your question here with more specific details about the problem you're having.

Comment: I know GET statuses/friends request  but i don't know how to use it. Can you give me a sample code for it? I want to get friends list and fill it into UITableView. Thanks you!