# how to get email of friends list using twitter api on iphone app

Tags: iphone, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve email from twitter profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889029/retrieve-email-from-twitter-profile)

Hi all, i using twiiter api to user login twitter on my app and get information of friends list of user, i want get email account of list friends. Can you help me? thanks!

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889029/retrieve-email-from-twitter-profile

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the email is not available via the API as far as I can find. http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation

Comment: can you help me how to do that without twitter api? Thanks  you!

Comment: No I can't since it not possible.